# Make div Background heigth at 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can i make my `div` background height at 100% depending on the height of it parent :
that's what i have for now :

[image]

and i want to fill all the space with the red color with the background color:

[image]

this is my HTML code :

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
        <div class="col-6"><img style="width: 100%" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/01/10/23/image-1635747_960_720.jpg"></div>
        <div class="col-6 class1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/01/10/23/image-1635747_960_720.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
    </div>
```

and that's my css :

```
.class1{
            background-color: yellow;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

and thanks for help :-)

Comment: can you please explain how the accepted answer solve you issue? we don't need to set width:100% ... you simply need to remove the height and the content will get stretched by default due to flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below link:
https://jsfiddle.net/ulric_469/7mh4vs6p/6/

add height 100% to the image

```
    .row {
     display: flex;
     align-items: stretch;
   }

   .row > div {
     flex: 1
   }
```